# when $n=12$ and $k=7$, can we generate a sub-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$\def\llg{\langle} \def\rrg{\rangle}$
There is a theorem that says if $|\llg a\rrg|=n$, then for each positive divisor $k$ of $n$, the group $\llg a\rrg$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$—namely, $\llg a^{n/k}\rrg$.

Assume $\llg a\rrg$ is a cyclic group of order $12$, i.e. $|\llg a\rrg|=12$.
Take $k=7$,
$$
\begin{align}
\llg a^7\rrg
&=
\{a^7,a^{14},a^{21},a^{28},a^{35},a^{42},a^{49},a^{56},a^{63},a^{70},a^{77},a^{84}\}\\
&=\{a^7,a^2,a^9,a^4,a^{11},a^6,a,a^8,a^3,a^{10},a^5,e\}\\
&=\llg a\rrg
\end{align}
$$

But $7$ does not divide $12$.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of $<a^{n/k}>$ the theorem took about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7$ does not divide $12$, which is why $\langle a \rangle$ has no subgroup of order $k$.

You have shown that $\langle a^7\rangle=\langle a \rangle$, which clearly shows that the order of the group $\langle a^7\rangle$ is **not** $7$, but is in fact $12$, so this result is entirely consistent with the theorem.

You also made an error. Taking $k=7$ and $n=12$, the expression $$\langle a^{\frac nk}\rangle$$ **does not** become the expression $$\langle a^7\rangle,$$ but rather the expression

$$\left\langle a^{\frac{12}{7}}\right\rangle$$

which, in the constext of your question, is ill defined, since you only define $a^x$ for integer values of $x$ (and, because $7$ is not a divisor of $12$, $\frac{12}{7}$ is **not** an integer).

Comment: Then what is the meaning of $<a^{n/k}>$?

Comment: @alFeraas The group, generated by $a$ to the power of $n$ divided by $k$. Which, when $k$ is not a divisor of $n$, is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for any non-zero integer $i$, the order of $a^i$, $o(a^i)=\frac{o(a)}{gcd(i,o(a))}$. So, if $o(a)=12$, then since $gcd(7,12)=1$, $o(a^7)=12$.